# Requests to /.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I just checked my server logs and found the following weird requests coming in quite a lot. I have iOS 9 Universal Linking implemented, but those requests are running against /apple-app-site-association as far as I know.

```
Jan 15 09:36:23 method=GET path="/.well-known/apple-app-site-association"
```

Has anyone else seen these patterns? Is this some known spamming or something?

Comment: I'm seeing this too, and it seems to be from Darwin/15.4.0 which is iOS 9.3.

Comment: Okay good to know I'm not the only one. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Seeing this as well. Do you have the GoogleAppIndexing installed?

Comment: Having a lot of logs like this too :/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

i believe iOS 9.3 introduced slightly different lookup logic around the apple-app-site-association file and the app handoff feature.

"Handoff first searches for the file in the .well-known subdirectory (for example, https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association), falling back to the top-level domain if you don’t use the .well-known subdirectory."

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10

Comment: the link for developer.apple.com is not found.

Answer (score 14):

I also received the following in my log:

```
[Mon Feb 29 12:34:53 2016] [error] [source 66.249.75.XXX] File does not exist: /public_path/apple-app-site-association
```

Where `XXX` in the log is a number between 0 to 255.

Then, I checked [Whois IP 66.249.69.0](http://www.whois.com/whois/66.249.69.0), [1](http://www.whois.com/whois/66.249.69.1), [2](http://www.whois.com/whois/66.249.69.2) ....... [255](http://www.whois.com/whois/66.249.69.255)

And what I found, All IP in range from [66.249.64.0](http://www.whois.com/whois/66.249.69.0) - [66.249.95.255](http://www.whois.com/whois/66.249.69.255) assigned to `Google Inc`. Wait are you kidding me, why google requesting `apple-app-site-association` on my server?

Because Google extending it's mapping to include information on associations between websites and specific iOS apps for [Google App Indexing for universal links from Google Search in Safari.](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app).

### Whois log for IP 66.249.64.0

```
NetRange:       66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255
CIDR:           66.249.64.0/19
NetName:        GOOGLE
NetHandle:      NET-66-249-64-0-1
Parent:         NET66 (NET-66-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Google Inc. (GOGL)
RegDate:        2004-03-05
Updated:        2012-02-24
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-66-249-64-0-1



OrgName:        Google Inc.
OrgId:          GOGL
Address:        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
City:           Mountain View
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94043
Country:        US
RegDate:        2000-03-30
Updated:        2015-11-06
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/GOGL


OrgAbuseHandle: ABUSE5250-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Abuse
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-650-253-0000 
OrgAbuseEmail:  email@google.com
OrgAbuseRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE5250-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: ZG39-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Google Inc
OrgTechPhone:  +1-650-253-0000 
OrgTechEmail:  email@google.com
OrgTechRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ZG39-ARIN
```

Answer (score 6):

We're seeing this behavior as well. The vast majority of our server's access log files are now requests for this particular file.

If you happen to be running a setup with nginx serving static files in front of an application server / framework, be sure to verify that the `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` AND `/apple-app-site-association` files either exist or return a response.

If they don't, the missing requests will all be passed along to your framework, which in many cases results in having to process your routes before determining that there is no match. Until we made that change yesterday, the added stress to our servers was fairly significant.

Comment: what if we leave these file empty ? @aramisbear

Comment: If they exist and are empty files nginx will still see them and serve them. That's all you'll need to keep it from passing those requests to the routing layer of your application.

Answer (score 6):

Since iOS 9.3 Apple will first try to download `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` and in case it fails it fallbacks to `/apple-app-site-association`.

See Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1919](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1919/_index.html):

> ## Incoming requests for /.well-known/apple-app-site-association file
>
> Q: Why is my web server receiving requests for https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association?
>
> A: The recently released iOS 9.3 update implements [RFC 5785](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5785.txt). Because of this, devices running iOS 9.3 will first request `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` for the `apple-app-site-association` file that is required to implement [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) and [Shared Web Credentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014989). If the file is not found in this location, then the device will request the file in the root of the web server, as with prior releases of iOS 9.

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing lots of these requests (both with and without the `.well-known` subdirectory). They come from `google-bot`, but I suppose other spiders might start looking for them, too, at some point. Since my site doesn't have any overlapping functionality with any `iOS` (or `Android`) app, they are a waste of bandwidth. I like @aramisbear's answer to protect my application server (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36185061/467590). But I'm going to try adding them to my `robots.txt` instead. Since `google-bot` respects `robots.txt` (and other bots interested in creating app indexes almost certainly would, too) I would assume that doing this will prevent wasting even my `nginx` proxy's bandwidth, too.

Comment: @Snovarg - Definitely. We have a very low-volume site, but hopes of becoming higher volume some day, so I thought I'd address this before it became an issue :-) Before I changed robots.txt on Nov 6 2016, we were getting a couple of these every couple of days, almost all from googlebot. Since making the change, we've received a grand total of 2 of these, both on Jan 7 2017, from applebot.

Comment: Good to hear @sootsnoot! My solution, to create empty files and folders for every strange request is somewhat tiresome, and maybe also stupid, as their systems might downvote my site. Could you help me out by posting an example of how you added this to robots.txt? (I am not well bewandered in these things..)

Comment: @Snovarg - Google robots.txt, plain text file with that name goes in your document root. The two relevant lines are just "Disallow: /.well-known/" and "Disallow: /apple-app-site-association" (without the quotes).

Comment: Thanks for the kickstarter. :)

Comment: exactly. i think it has something to do with SEO. see:
IP: 66.249.64.212
site: http://hambazar.com/ .well-known/apple-app-site-association
Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)